# What does ::open mean?

Tags: c++, syntax, fstream

I need help understanding C++ syntax. I am referencing Derek Molloy [Github](https://github.com/derekmolloy/exploringBB),

> /Chp08/i2c/cpp/I2CDevice.cpp

In his implementation file, he has this section in his code

```
int I2CDevice::open(){
   string name;
   if(this->bus==0) name = BBB_I2C_0;
   else name = BBB_I2C_1;

   if((this->file=::open(name.c_str(), O_RDWR)) < 0){
      perror("I2C: failed to open the bus\n");
      return 1;
   }
   if(ioctl(this->file, I2C_SLAVE, this->device) < 0){
      perror("I2C: Failed to connect to the device\n");
      return 1;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I am confused on this particular line,
`if((this->file=::open(name.c_str(), O_RDWR)) < 0)`. What exactly does `=::open` mean? I know the fstream library in C++ has an open method, but why include the `::`?

Comment: `::open` means "use the `open` function that is in the global namespace".

Comment: ^ and don't recursively call `int I2CDevice::open()`

Comment: Since, his method is also "open", including :: helps prevents any confusion between the standard open method in the fstream library and his method ? Just making sure I understood your response @Elijay.

Comment: Thank you! I do appreciate the help guys.

Comment: `=::` is two tokens, `=` and `::`. Writing them with no space in between can be confusing to readers, but the compiler knows.

Answer (score 3):

`name::func()` means to calling `func` under the namespace `name`. Some functions like `open` are defined in the global namespace which has no name, so `::open` calls a function named `open` from the global namespace. It is used here to avoid calling `I2CDevice::open` and to explicitly call the operating system's `open` function.

Answer (score 0):

When doing a function call you can prefix the function with the namespace it is in:

```
<NameSpaceDecl>::<Function>(<Param>);
```

This usually looks like this:

```
std::sort(begin, end);
```

But things in the global namespace, can be accessed by the shorter `::`

```
::open(<Stuff>);
```

So this is a way of specifying a specific function when the compiler may have picked a function from a local scope instead.

In your case you probably need to use `::open()` as your class has  function `I2CDevice::open()` and the compiler would have tried to use that one (and generated an error). But by being specific with `::open()` you are saying use the version of `open()` that is in the global namespace.